# Rails, find table where match another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

How to find table values with matching id with other table.
I have this tables:

```
Zombie_users      Body_status                             

| id | name |     | id| Zombie_id| body_id | status|   
|----|------| --> |---|----------|---------|-------|
| 1  | Joe  |     | 1 |    1     |     2   | true  |   



Zobmie_users      Tools                   Body_impacts

| id | name |    | id |user_id| name |    | id| tool_id| body_id | impact |
|----|------|--> |----|-------|------|--> |---|--------|---------|--------|
| 1  | Joe  |    | 1  |   1   |hammer|    | 1 |    1   |    2    |   10%  |
```

I need to find all the `user -> tools` that have `user --> Body_status = false`.
I mean if we have `Body_impact -> body_id -> 2` and `Body_status -> body_id -> 2` that also have `status = true` exclude that tool from the list

samething like that:

```
@Body_status = @zombie.Body_status.where( Body_status: { :status=> false } )

@tools = @zombie.tools.includes(:Body_impacts).where( @Body_status.body_id } )
```

I know that's not working code, but it perfectly explains the logic of the desired action.

**update**

My models:

```
class ZombieUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :body_statuses
 has_many :bodies, through: :body_statuses
 has_many :tools

class BodyStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombie_users
  belongs_to :bodies

class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombie_users
  has_many :body_impacts
  has_many :bodies, :through => :body_impacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :body_impacts, 

class BodysImpact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tools
 belongs_to :bodies
```

Comment: Can you post your models with associations in the question?

Comment: please put your association here.

Comment: @Pavan , Thanks, I added the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clean up some of those calls with [ActiveRecord association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/zombie.rb
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :body_statuses do
      def false
         where status: false
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@zombie = Zombie.find 1
@statuses = @zombie.body_statuses.false
```

---

> I mean if we have `Body_impact -> body_id -> 2` and `Body_status -> body_id -> 2` that also have `status = true` exclude that tool from the list

I think you could build a query like this:

```
@zombie = Zombie.find 1
@statuses = @zombie.body_statuses.false.pluck(:body_id) #-> array of IDs with "false" status

@user.tools.joins(:body_impacts).where('body_impacts.body_id IN (?)', @statuses)
## or
@user.tools.joins(:body_impacts).find_by(id: @statuses)
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Only the second option not working as expected.
I was able to get it to work only this way:
`@user.tools.joins(:body_impacts).find_by(body_impacts: { body_id: @statuses})`